# Cheap way to hang a poster without frame

Tags: home, substitute-tool

I bought a poster 135*85 cm without a frame.

When i try to hang the poster with double-sided tape on a self made wooden frame, the poster will be down in a few hours.

Because of the size there are no click systems available.

How can i easy and cheap hang the poster?

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to hang it in a frame, or hang it without framing it? What material is the wall?

Comment: Also: what material is the poster? Is it extremely thick thus making it extremely heavy?

Comment: The poster is paper with a polish layer. Not extremely heavy! 
I tried to hang the poster with a small wooden frame but the double-sided tape wasn't strong enought. I Can use the frame again!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this qualifies as a life-hack, because you have the standard options of:

- Nailing/stapling it to the frame
- Using tape, either double-side or single-sided. Use more if it falls down...
- Using some sticky goo, like blu-tack or similar stuff
- Depending on your frame, add a back panel or front frame, and wedge the poster between these (Could also be done using plexi glass panels)
- Glue it onto the frame

Comment: Think that this are all my options! Thank you. 
Something like "No lifehacks available"

Answer (score 5):

I have had great success in the past using binder/bulldog clips. The larger the poster, the larger the clips need to be (and/or more need to be used) but I have found that simply clipping a couple to the top of the poster works very well -- the 'wire' part of the clip can then be hung on a nail or similar, with no need for a frame. If the poster doesn't hang perfectly straight, you can use an additional clip at the bottom to 'weight' it.

The only risk from this method is a little creasing around where the clip 'bites' but I expect that would be less bad than marks left by tape.

[image: Poster hung using binder clip]

Answer (score 4):

Bulldog clips may be superior to binder clips depending on the material of the poster you are attempting to hang, as well as the aesthetics you are going for in your presentation of this work of art.
[image: Bulldog clip]

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could try to use some Super Bonder. This way it will REALLY hang it, but beware that it's kinda hard to remove it once applied.

[image]

Comment: Its possible, but i'am moving out in a couple of months and want to take the poster with me.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a removable spray adhesive. Super 77 seems to work well for this, but the paper can tear if the bond is too strong. Prevent this by not applying a super thick spray, and by waiting at least a minute before sticking the poster to the wall.

Answer (score 0):

I am particularly fond of using thumb tacks to hang objects. They have multiple uses and are removable. The only downside is that it will leave a tiny hole in the poster. I recommend of course using clear so that no colors are distracting from the poster's image. Depending on what type of frame you have, you can thumb tac the poster to the wooden frame in the top two corners, and then use another 1,2, or 3 thumb tacks (depending on weight) to hang the wooden frame. This all depends on weight. If you want to get creative, you can take some durable string or fabric cut into a strand and use it with the thumb tacks for a neat effect. It is all about weight balancing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some Hacks / 5 creative ways
 http://www.athomeinlove.com/5-creative-ways-to-hang-artwork-without-a-frame/

Otherwise,  try a thin piece of custom sized  plexiglass or acrylic that can overlap the poster with some alternative hanging options!