# Hanging pictures on the wall without nails/tacks/normal tape?

Tags: home

I am looking to hang 4x6 photographs on a wall in my room. They will not be in a frame of any sort, just the photo paper. I have about 100 and am going to make a collage. I tried glue dots, but they blew off the wall and all my pictures fell down. I do not want to see the method I use to hang the pictures, only the pictures. Is there a better solution? Thanks!

Edit: My concern is mainly the pictures staying on the wall. (As well as cost because I do have about 100 pictures to hang)

(Note: please do not suggest painters tape, scotch tape, tacs, thumb nails, nails etc)

Comment: related https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7852/how-can-i-hang-a-picture-without-being-able-to-drive-nails-hooks-into-the-wall and http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7260/cheap-way-to-hang-a-poster-without-frame

Comment: In one of the related questions, as suggested by crabolo, there is a suggestions for [a removal spray adhesive (named Super77)](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/7895/4490) which might be more applicable in your case than in those cases.

Answer (score 3):

If your concern is damage to the wall, you may want to consider a product such as the Command range of picture hanging products from 3M.

These are designed for damage free hanging, they hold strongly and remove cleanly. I have used the hook versions of these, but the [picture strips](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Command-Picture-Hanging-Strips-Value/dp/B000OF6X48) look like they will work for your application.